# Rails + Carrierwave: How to link to file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Catalog` that has an attribute called file:

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, CatalogUploader
```

How would I create a link that would show that file in the browser?

I tried

```
<%= link_to "zzzz", catalog.file_url %>
```

but when I click that link it just gives me a routing error

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/Users/emai/Documents/mysite/catalogs/2/vegetarian.png"
```

And the URL doesn't look correct either: `http://localhost:3000/Users/emai/Documents/mysite/catalogs/2/vegetarian.png`. I know the pic exists because I made a link to download the file, and that worked properly. However, I want to show the pic instead.

CatalogUploader:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class CatalogUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
      "#{Rails.root}/public/test/file_uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    else
      "#{Rails.root}/catalogs/#{model.id}"
    end
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :scale => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Comment: Try `<%= link_to "zzzz", catalog.file_url, method: :get%>`

Comment: Can you share the code for `CatalogUploader`.

Comment: @Pavan link_to is by default GET. You can see it in the error as well.

Comment: I updated the question with my uploader file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the `store_dir` method in `CatalogUploader` as below:

```
 def store_dir
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
      "#{Rails.root}/public/test/file_uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    else
      "#{Rails.root}/public/catalogs/#{model.id}"  ## Should be in public folder
    end
  end
```

The images must be present in `public` folder so that they are accessible from web. If they are not, then Rails would try to locate its route in `routes.rb`.

Also, I think you would need to change `Catalog` model as below:

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, CatalogUploader, mount_on: :file
```

As per the docs:

> :mount_on => Symbol
>
> if the name of the column to be serialized to differs you can override it using this option

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord), you should do call the method `url` of the file object like this :

```
<%= link_to "zzzz", catalog.file.url %>
```

Comment: I tried that and it still returns the same link and the same routing error

Comment: It seems I was wrong. `file.url` and `file_url` is the same thing.